# How to Disable/hide Tooltips in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, hide

This is how I set my tooltips:

```
if(Globals.isShowTooltips()) {
    locale = new Locale(Globals.getGuiLanguage());
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lang", locale);            

    btnSettingsApply.setTooltip(
        new Tooltip(bundle.getString("btnSettingsApplyt")));

    btnSettingsOk.setTooltip(
        new Tooltip(bundle.getString("btnSettingsOkt")));

    btnSettingsCancel.setTooltip(
        new Tooltip(bundle.getString("btnSettingsCancelt")));            
}
```

How can I hide tooltips? It seems to me that there isn't a straight-forward approach for this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `tooltip.setOpacity(0.0);` works for me (I do this in cases where the tooltip would be empty and found this to be a liitle bit easier than uninstalling / re-installing)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For Controls**

Controls have a [setter for tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setTooltip-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-).  So for controls, use that.

To set the tooltip on a control:

```
btnSettingsOk.setTooltip(new Tooltip("OK Button"));
```

To remove the tooltip on a control:

```
btnSettingsOk.setTooltip(null);
```

**For Nodes which are not Controls**

Layout panes, shapes and other nodes do not have a setter for tooltips (because tooltips are classified as controls and the JavaFX developers wanted to avoid a dependence of the general scene graph nodes on the controls package).  However those nodes can still work with tooltips using the static [`install`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) and [`uninstall`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#uninstall-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) methods.

This is pretty much Ikallas's answer, though I would only advise using it when the node type in question does not supply an explicit `setTooltip` method - even though it will also work for controls.  The set method on controls is simpler to use because the control stores a reference to the Tooltip, whereas, for an static uninstall, your application is responsible for keeping the reference to the tooltip so that it can later remove it.

To set the tooltip on a Node which is not a control:

```
Tooltip okTooltip = new Tooltip("OK Button");
Tooltip.install(btnSettingsOk, okTooltip)));
```

To remove the tooltip from a Node which is not a control:

```
Tooltip.uninstall(btnSettingsOk, okTooltip);
```

Comment: Good answer! Made JavaFX tooltips more understandable for me ;)

Comment: @jewelsea see my comment on Ikallas answer. You don´t need the tooltip parameter on Tooltip.uninstall(). It´s not used at all (look at the implementation)

Comment: Public API includes the tooltip to uninstall as the second parameter to the [uninstall](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#uninstall-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) method.  So I'd be inclined to pass the correct tooltip to uninstall to the method regardless of what the implementation does (even though, as you point out in your other comment, the parameter is not used in the current internal implementation for Java 8).  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just found answer to my own question :)

```
Tooltip.install(btnSettingsOk, new Tooltip(bundle.getString("btnSettingsOkt"))); //This is for showing

Tooltip.uninstall(btnSettingsOk, new Tooltip(bundle.getString("btnSettingsOkt"))); //This is for disabling
```

If there is some better way I would like to know about it ;)

Comment: Another way would be to just set the tooltip to null. Then re-applying it when you need it. But I think your own solution might be better ;)

Comment: Just came across this and you don´t need the second parameter on uninstall. Pretty heavy API fail if you ask me but the second parameter isn´t used at all.
public static void uninstall(Node node, Tooltip t) {
        BEHAVIOR.uninstall(node);
    }